# Не могу изменить цвет элемента с помощью JS

Tags: javascript

в консоли Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'backgroundColor')

```
for (var i = 0 ; i < right.length; i++) {
   right[i].addEventListener('click' , function(){
       console.log('норм');
       right.style.backgroundColor = "red";
   } ) ; 
}
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: right это кнопка, в переменной содержится. пробовала и background и backgroundColor, не идёт всё равно, в чем дело может быть?

Comment: я все равно не могу понять для чего  здесь цикл? и какой результат ожидается?

Comment: right если быть точнее, это массив кнопок, при нажатии меняется цвет. в массиве без цикла for addEventListener не работает. я пробовала также и с 1 элементом, но также выходит Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'backgroundColor')

Comment: Судя по всему, `right` - это массив html элементов и вы забыли указать индекс. `right[i].style.backgroundColor = "red";`

Comment: Весь код предоставьте.  Исходя из ошибки " не возможно установить свойство не определённого обьекта

Comment: @xydope В этом случае, индекс нужно объявить как `let i = 0`

Comment: @LaukhinAndrey всё верно, внимание даже не обратил, настолько редко `var` вижу. :D

Comment: да, дело в индексе, спасибо

Answer (score 2):

`right` - это, судя по всему, коллекция элементов.
Если требуется изменить цвет элемента, по которому был клик, то следует взять его из аргумента функции-обработчика события:

```js
let right = document.querySelectorAll('.box');

for (let i = 0; i < right.length; i++) {
  right[i].addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    event.target.style.backgroundColor = "red";
  });
}
```

```css
.box {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
```